# Why/How is it that some classes require every possible argument, and some don't?

Tags: python, parameters, tkinter, arguments

I've been using tkinter recently with Python, and I've been confused about the way arguments are passed when creating an instance of an object in tkinter.

When I create a class myself, every argument that is possible to be passed, *has* to be passed. However, when creating an instance of any widget in tkinter, not every possible argument has to be passed immediately. They each default to a specific value. Consider this code which is used to create a canvas widget:

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 250)
```

The values (400, 25) don't even need to be passed in order, they are identified by the name (width, height) which comes before the value. There are other values that I could have specified, (e.g.: background, border), but there is no need to because the default values are fine.

I've searched around for a long time trying to find the answer, but, since I'm not entirely sure what to call these special arguments, It's very hard to find anything written about this.

Comment: See [this section in the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is something called, default parameters,

   ```
   def default_parameters(var1 = "cabbage"):
       print var1

   default_parameters(var1 = "salad")     # salad
   default_parameters("salad")            # salad
   default_parameters()                   # cabbage
   default_parameters("salad", "cabbage") # Error! Expects only one parameter
   ```

   Here, if no parameters are passed, the default value specified in the definition is assumed.
2. If you want to accept many parameters, you can unpack them in the arguments section like this

   ```
   def many_parameters(var1,  var2 = "cabbage", *args):
       print var1, var2, args

   many_parameters("salad", "cabbage", "rabbit", "ninja", "puppy")
   # salad cabbage ('rabbit', 'ninja', 'puppy')
   many_parameters("salad", "cabbage", "rabbit", "ninja")
   # salad cabbage ('rabbit', 'ninja')
   many_parameters("salad", "cabbage", "rabbit")
   # salad cabbage ('rabbit',)
   many_parameters("salad", "cabbage")
   # salad cabbage
   many_parameters("salad")
   # salad cabbage
   many_parameters()
   # many_parameters() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
   many_parameters("salad", var2 = "ninja", "puppy")
   # SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
   many_parameters("salad", "puppy", var2 = "ninja")
   # many_parameters() got multiple values for keyword argument 'var2'
   ```

   Here, in the first case, the `salad` and `cabbage` are assigned to `var1` and `var2`, but rest of the values are assigned to `args` as a tuple.

   The second and third cases are same as the first one.

   The fourth case has got no extra parameters, so `args` will be empty.

   The fifth case has got no extra parameters, and no value for `var2`, so `args` will be empty and the default value (`cabbage`) is assumed for `var2`.

   In the sixth case, `var1` hasn't got any default value provided. So, it fails with `at-least 1 argument expected` error.

   In the seventh case, `var2` (a named variable) is used before an unnamed parameter. That is wrong in Python.

   In the eighth case, both `var2` (a named variable) and `puppy` (*positional parameter*) are being set to `var2`. Now, Python cannot decide which value to use for `var2`. So, it fails.
3. In the previous cases, we saw how to handle default parameters and named parameters. Now, named parameters are also called as keyword arguments, which is conventionally represented as `**kwargs`, which is actually a dictionary of key-value pairs of all the named parameters. **Note:** Default parameters don't count as keyword parameters.

   ```
   def all_parameters(var1, var2 = "cabbage", *args, **kwargs):
       print var1, var2, args, kwargs

   all_parameters("salad", "cabbage", "rabbit")
   # salad cabbage ('rabbit',) {}
   all_parameters("salad", "cabbage")
   # salad cabbage () {}
   all_parameters("salad")
   # salad cabbage () {}
   all_parameters("salad", var2 = "ninja", "puppy")
   # SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
   all_parameters("salad", "puppy", var2 = "ninja")
   # all_parameters() got multiple values for keyword argument 'var2'
   all_parameters("salad", moderator="jonclements", python="martijinpieters")
   # salad cabbage () {'moderator': 'jonclements', 'python': 'martijinpieters'}
   ```

   I believe, except the last item all others are already covered in the previous two examples. In the last case, all the non-default but named parameters are stored in `kwargs` dictionary.

**Note:** Remember the `*` in `*args` and `**` in `**kwargs`, in the function definition. They are responsible for the packing of the parameters passed to the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example.

```
def spam(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    print a, b, c
```

This function has three arguments, all of which have default values. So I could use this function in a lot of ways.

```
>>> spam() # uses the default values
1 2 3 
>>> spam(3) # use default for b and c
3 2 3
>>> spam(c=4, b=2, a=6) # explicitly assign values
6 2 4
>>> spam(b=7) # only assign b, use defaults for a and c
1 7 3
```

Something similar to this happens with the Canvas widget. You can see the reference here:
https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a method you can specify default values. Eg.:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c=True, d="default value"):
    ....
```